# Is it possible to add link tags under Matter.js?

Tags: javascript, html, css, matter.js

Im trying to put links in the screen, I guess it is not successful due to Matter.js.
You can see the links but you cannot press on the them.

there is any way to make it work?

link to github:
https://github.com/harelpanker/constarctions

```css
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: content-box;
}

html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

body {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  background: #333;
  text-align: center;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 30px white;
  cursor: -webkit-grab;
  cursor: grab;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
     -moz-user-select: none;
      -ms-user-select: none;
          user-select: none;
}
```

```html
<footer class="footer">
    <h3>Burgschmietstraße 10, 90419 Nuremberg</h3>
    <nav class="nav-footer">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="tel:+49 911 424480">+49 911 424480</a></li>
        <li><a href="mailto:hello@dkdl.de">hello@dkdl.de</a></li>
        <li><a href="https://www.google.com/maps?q=Burgschmietstra%C3%9Fe+10,+Nuremberg,+Germany&hl=en&ie=UTF8&ll=49.458086,11.071386&spn=0.001972,0.002494&sll=37.0625,-95.677068&sspn=55.016555,81.738281&hnear=Burgschmietstra%C3%9Fe+10,+90419+Nuremberg,+Mittelfranken,+Bayern,+Germany&t=h&z=19">route</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">imprint</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">privacy policy</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </footer>
```

I expect to press the links...

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want it be 'body' I want it to be static on the screen where the outers 'body's' will fly/hover over the links...

Comment: just try adding `.footer { z-index: 2 }`

Comment: It is working, But I was needed to add it also to SCSS... THANKS!